# C# generic class - How to replace a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, generics

I'm having a little trouble at C#

I have a generic class to work with the EntityFramework like this one:

```
public void update(TEntity entity)
{
    try
    {

        using (db = new SystemEntities())
        {
            db.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.GetType() == typeof(DbEntityValidationException))
        {
            DbEntityValidationException error = (DbEntityValidationException)e;

            foreach (var validationErrors in error.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Log.write(String.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
        }

        Log.write(e);
    }
}
```

I need to check if the TEntity has a property called "last_update", and, if it does, I have to set a DateTime.Now at it.

I was trying something like this:

```
PropertyInfo myproperty = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("last_update");
bool existUpdate = myobj.GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Equals("last_update")).Any();
if (existUpdate) 
{
    entity.last_update = DateTime.Now;
}
```

but c# returns an exception saying that there's not a definition for last_update in entity. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    PropertyInfo myproperty = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("last_update");
    if (myproperty != null)
        myproperty.SetValue(myobj, DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would introduce an interface at entity level

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity : IAuditable
{
    ...
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can test for in your repository

```
var trackableObj = myobj as IAuditable;
if (trackableObj != null)
    trackableObj.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PropertyInfo myproperty = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("last_update");
 if (myproperty != null)
 {
     myproperty.SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now);
 }
```